# Finding the maximum Eigen vector in MATLAB

Tags: matrices

I am trying to apply something I learned in paper regarding finding the maximum eigenvector of a matrix. Lets assume the matrix is $T$ and the max eigen vector of matrix ${\bf T}$ is ${\bf w}$

$${\bf w} =\max  \,eigenvector \, { \bf T}$$

I am trying to implement this in MATLAB, there are four options I am confused with and dont know what to use

```
[V,e]= eigs(T)
w = T(:,1)
```

or

```
[V,e]= eigs(transpose(conj(T))*T)
w = T(:,1)
```

or

```
[V,e]= eigs(transpose(T*conj(T)))
w = T(:,1)
```

or

```
[U,Sigma,Vh]= svd(T)
w = Vh(:,1) or w= U(:,1)
```

Thanks looking forward for your help.

Comment: Only the first one is guaranteed to have anything to do with the problem, under no additional assumptions about $T$. But if $T$ is Hermitian, then all of these should give essentially the same answer (up to numerical error).

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum eigenvector"?  I could understand "maximum eigenvalue" (if the eigenvalues are real).

Comment: @RobertIsrael this was literally what was written in the published paper, I think they mean the eigenvector corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue...